# Possible to test website with GAE over LAN in Mountain Lion?

Tags: google-app-engine, osx-mountain-lion

I'm hosting my website using Google App Engine. It's a pretty simple website, but I've got some javascript drawing to a canvas element, which I'm trying to test on my iPhone. I'd also like to take a crack at reworking my CSS for mobile. However, I can't access `http://localhost:8080/` (which is the url that GoogleAppEngineLauncher spits out when I run the app locally) from my phone. This seems obvious.

Unfortunately, it seems that Mountain Lion has removed the web sharing preference from system preferences. I found at least [two](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57481978-263/how-to-enable-web-sharing-in-os-x-mountain-lion/) [different](http://www.codepotato.co.uk/2012/07/25/enabling-localhost-on-os-x-mountain-lion/) sites with "solutions" for re-activating web sharing (Apache server?), but none of them seem to work in conjuction with Google App Engine... I also tried this [preference pane](http://clickontyler.com/blog/2012/02/web-sharing-mountain-lion/), which *also* doesn't work. I keep getting "Safari cannot open the page because it could not connect to the server."

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm a relative noob to this stuff. Also, I see a lot of questions here on SO which seem related, but I think I'm still too uninitiated to understand *how* they're releated. Is there an extra step here that's GAE specific which I'm missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't anything specific to your OS. By default, the App Engine dev server binds to the loopback interface, making it accessible only to your machine. If you want to access it from other machines, you need to pass the `--address=0.0.0.0` flag to the dev server - which you can do in the launcher's preference pane.

Comment: that sounds like just what I was looking for! unfortunately, the preference pane only has two fields -- 'Python Path' and 'Code Editor'... am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: ... double clicked the app in the launcher and I got a popup sheet with a field under 'Launch Settings' which is called 'Extra Flags'. That totally worked! I have to specify the machine's name/url on the device, but it's functioning now! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As of March 2013 - the "address" argument has been renamed to "host" - (at least for Python version of the app engine)

- [--address=0.0.0.0 argument not working after upgrading to App Engine 1.7.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513064/address-0-0-0-0-argument-not-working-after-upgrading-to-app-engine-1-7-6)