# Exposing localhost:8080 (PubSubHubBub hub) to Internet on AWS

Tags: python, google-app-engine, publish-subscribe, atom-feed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Possible to test website with GAE over LAN in Mountain Lion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13277538/possible-to-test-website-with-gae-over-lan-in-mountain-lion)

I've got a hub running on localhost from [this](http://www.liangeugene.com/2011/02/running-pubsubhubbub-on-ubuntu-10-04-python-2-6/) example.  But as my `lynx`-browser is not too hot on `jQuery` scripts, I need to expose the admin console to the internet. Hitting my AWS server on the internet doesn't work (ie. the `ec2-13-13-341-3.aws.amazon.com:80/8080`).

How can I forward/whatever the localhost:8080 to be accessed from outside at :80 ?

Thanks.

(Also, if anyone knows any good tutorials for setting up a PubSubHubBub Hub with Python on a Ubuntu box in Amazon AWS, PLEASE do not hesitate to let me know! ;)

Comment: Note that you should never ever use this to expose a development server to the outside world - it's emphatically _not_ designed to be used as a production webserver, and is not secure.

Comment: @NickJohnson Thanks for that. What should I do to put it securely out in public?

Comment: Host it on App Engine, or if you really don't want to do that, use AppScale or TyphoonAE.

Answer (score 1):

If you can access the "system" for lack of a better word, from `http://localhost:8080` then you should also be able to access it from the computer's local IP. For example `192.168.1.5:8080` on my computer. You can then access that from any computer on your network.
Note you have to change the IP address to your local IP.

This won't solve redirecting port 80 to 8080, but I believe port forwarding on your router can help with that.

Comment: Nope, if the server bound to 127.0.0.1 it will *not* be visible on the public interface. You'd need to bind to 0.0.0.0 for it to be visible to all interfaces.