# --address=0.0.0.0 argument not working after upgrading to App Engine 1.7.6

Tags: google-app-engine, dev-appserver, dev-appserver-2

I just upgraded to the latest version of App Engine which is usually a good thing and just works. Now when I try to launch dev_appserver (the new multithreaded version) I get:

dev_appserver.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --address=0.0.0.0

I've reviewed the new parameters but don't see what I need to change this parameter to so that I can still access the dev_appserver across my network using the machineName.local:port syntax which I really like to use.

Any ideas?

---

Google notes that I can use old_dev_appserver.py in the short term. That's good feedback. I am also looking for the long term solution.

Comment: How did you get a response from Danny Hermes?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe this parameter was renamed to --host

Comment: Correct,   it is also documented - always worth RTFM when there is a new release ;-) 

`https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver`

Comment: 1. Tim is correct. The "address" argument has been renamed to "host".
* * * * *

2. I did not see mention of the argument change from "address" to "host" in the release notes where I would expect to see changes like that.


https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes

Comment: 3. The options in the old_dev_appserver.py were more self documenting.

`Options:
  --address=ADDRESS, -a ADDRESS
  Address to which this server should bind. (Default localhost).`


The new usage output didn't lead me to "host" being the same argument.

`usage: dev_appserver.py [-h] [--host HOST] [--admin_host ADMIN_HOST]`